# find branch name inside CheckinHandlerFactory in Idea plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to write a plugin for an idea that will check the commit for the established writing rules. In particular, it is necessary to compare the commit message with the branch to which it will be sent. I tried to inherit from the CheckinHandlerFactory, the commit text is present in the CommitContext, but I don't understand how to get the branch name.

here is my code:

```
public class BeforeCommitPlugin extends CheckinHandlerFactory {

    @Override
    public @NotNull CheckinHandler createHandler(@NotNull CheckinProjectPanel panel,
                                                 @NotNull CommitContext commitContext) {
        return new CheckinHandler() {
            @Override
            public @Nullable RefreshableOnComponent getBeforeCheckinConfigurationPanel() {
                return super.getBeforeCheckinConfigurationPanel();
            }

            @Override
            public @Nullable UnnamedConfigurable getBeforeCheckinSettings() {
                return super.getBeforeCheckinSettings();
            }

            @Override
            public @Nullable RefreshableOnComponent getAfterCheckinConfigurationPanel(Disposable parentDisposable) {
                return super.getAfterCheckinConfigurationPanel(parentDisposable);
            }

            @Override
            public ReturnResult beforeCheckin(@Nullable CommitExecutor executor, PairConsumer<Object, Object> additionalDataConsumer) {
                return super.beforeCheckin(executor, additionalDataConsumer);
            }

            @Override
            public ReturnResult beforeCheckin() {
                CommitMessageStyleChecker checker = new CommitMessageStyleChecker(panel.getCommitMessage());
                if (!checker.getCommitErrors().isEmpty()){
                    return ReturnResult.CANCEL;
                } else {
                    return ReturnResult.COMMIT;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void checkinSuccessful() {
                super.checkinSuccessful();
            }

            @Override
            public void checkinFailed(List<VcsException> exception) {
                super.checkinFailed(exception);
            }

            @Override
            public void includedChangesChanged() {
                super.includedChangesChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean acceptExecutor(CommitExecutor executor) {
                return super.acceptExecutor(executor);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I tried to find the right field inside the panel, but failed

Answer (score 0):

Branch name is not stored there.
You take the files from the `CheckinProjectPanel`, find GitRepository for them (GitRepositoryManager), and call getCurrentBranch on it.